# 3 level Drilldown of a column chart in highchart?

Tags: php, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to implement 3 LEVEL Column drill down report. I'm showing scores based on `agent->customer->question`

I am using the chart made by fusher for reference I have already [implemented it using php](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/NULTY/)

1. I want to implement scrolling in this [chart example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fj6d2/)
   which has you see is line chart.  How do I achieve a column drilldown scrolling when you have too much data on x axis.
2. I want to disable legend click (it causes the column chart to disappear)
3. Is a next previous button possible when drilling inside column depending on which column you are in it will take you the next drill or back. At present you have to drill through all levels to come back or a button to bring chart to initial or refresh the chart kinda something I am looking.
4. chart is not rendering in ie7 and ie8 its working fine with mozilla and chrome ie shows errors.
5. if I load the charts with local version of highcharts downloaded on my pc . for negative column in drill down it shows extra columns.

But in js fiddle with latest version of highcharts on highcharts sever it works fine don't know the strange behaviour.

Comment: i would like more answer from everone experiences :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i achieved the goal of a 3 level drill down with coulmn  charts in highcharts

thanks to fusher for his examples

has i said

now i have  a working chart where i need to pass the php data manually :)

this is the working js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/1200/

showing 3level drill on first column . i will update with the php code when done :)

```
edit: fixed jsFiddle link with working dependencies
```

Comment: I know that this topic is old, but could you please update it with php code to dynamically create 3lvl drilldown?