# Highchart Drilldown Multiple Layers

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I did some searching and couldn't find a concrete no to this question, so here goes.  Can Highcharts handle more than one level of drilling down/showing data?  Say 2-3 layers deep from the initial data view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

via [3 level Drilldown of a column chart in highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087253/3-level-drilldown-of-a-column-chart-in-highchart)

[Third link on Google for me](https://www.google.com/search?q=highcharts+drilldown+multiple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 0):

Made a 3 layer JS Fiddle:
only works for IE, first item (as test)
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6nL845z/)

```
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    {
                       name: 'v11.0',
                        y: 24.13,
                        drilldown: 'test'
                    },
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        17.2
                    ],
                    [
                        'v9.0',
                        8.11
                    ],
                    [
                        'v10.0',
                        5.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.0',
                        1.06
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.5
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v40.0',
                        5
                    ],
                    [
                        'v41.0',
                        4.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v42.0',
                        3.68
                    ],
                    [
                        'v39.0',
                        2.96
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36.0',
                        2.53
                    ],
                    [
                        'v43.0',
                        1.45
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31.0',
                        1.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v35.0',
                        0.85
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38.0',
                        0.6
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32.0',
                        0.55
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37.0',
                        0.38
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33.0',
                        0.19
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34.0',
                        0.14
                    ],
                    [
                        'v30.0',
                        0.14
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v35',
                        2.76
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36',
                        2.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37',
                        2.31
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34',
                        1.27
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38',
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31',
                        0.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33',
                        0.22
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32',
                        0.15
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        2.56
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.1',
                        0.77
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.1',
                        0.42
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.0',
                        0.3
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.1',
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.26
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.2',
                        0.17
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v12.x',
                        0.34
                    ],
                    [
                        'v28',
                        0.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v27',
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        'v29',
                        0.16
                    ]
                ]
            },{
                name: 'test',
                id: 'test',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v12.x',
                        0.34
                    ],
                    [
                        'v28',
                        0.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v27',
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        'v29',
                        0.16
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```