# Highcharts level 3 drill down does not work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have utilizing Highcharts to group data for each month, week, day, and also the same data for the previous month, week, and day. I seem to have figured out how to achieve the drill down to the second level but can't get the third level to show. Please let me know where my mistake is.

Here is a sample of the drill down I am working on:

```
categories0 = ['Current Month', 'Previous Month'],
        name0 = "RP",
        level = 0,
            data0 = [{
                y: 80,
                    drilldown: {
                    level : 1,
                    categories: ['Current Week', 'Previous Week'],
                    name0: 'RP',
                    data0: [50,45],
                    name1: 'PS',
                    data1: [35, 62],
                    name2: 'Rep',
                    data2: [65, 92],
                    name3: 'CR',
                    data3: [85, 92],
                        drilldown: {
                        level:2,
                        categories: ['Current Day', 'Last Day'],
                        name0: 'RP',
                        data0: [56,45],
                        name1: 'PS',
                        data1: [75, 62],
                        name2: 'Rep',
                        data2: [25, 92],
                        name3: 'CR',
                        data3: [25, 82],  
                        }
                    }
        }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/copperspeed/TGsTf/

Comment: What do you mean by drilldown?  What is the intended behavior?

Comment: Have you used Highcharts before?

Comment: Yep, I use it every day.

Comment: Then you must know about the drilldown feature in Highcharts, right?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com.  Generally when you ask a question you need to have a good problem statement associated so that when others peer into your code that doesn't work and is poorly written they can understand what it is you were trying to do.  As it stands, I can't deduce your problem from your description nor your fiddle and hope that someone else can come who knows every intended behavior of every method in the Highcharts API comes along.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087253/3-level-drilldown-of-a-column-chart-in-highchart.